# How do you Automatically Start Another Background Song in Processing?

Tags: processing

When the song (the age of consent) ends how do I start another one after it ends? This is what I have so far.

```
import processing.sound.*;
SoundFile file; 

void setup() {
  file = new SoundFile(this, "neworder.mp3");
  file.play();
  file.amp(0.25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The setup() method is only called once in processing. When processing starts running it calls an inbuilt draw() method continuously in a loop.

its in here you would need to check if the song has finished and load a new one.

```
void draw() {
    background(200, 100, 50,255);

     // YOUR CODE HERE TO CHECK IF SONG HAS FINISHED AND PLAY A BETTER SONG LIKE PO BOYDs - BLUE THREE ;)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the [processing.org SoundFile reference](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/SoundFile.html) is ommiting a few helpful functionalities of the class like [`percent()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-sound/processing/sound/AudioSample.html#percent--) or [`position()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-sound/processing/sound/AudioSample.html#position--)

You could so something like:

```
import processing.sound.*;
SoundFile file; 

void setup() {
  file = new SoundFile(this, "neworder.mp3");
  file.play();
  file.amp(0.25);
}

void draw(){
   if(file.percent() >= 99.8){
      println("track pretty close to done: cue out / cross fade here");
      file.stop();
   }

   background(0);
   text(file.percent(),5,15);
}
```

You can then either load/play another track or better yet:

1. load two tracks in `setup()` but play only one
2. when the first track is close to being done, start the second track at 0 volume
3. use [`lerp()`](https://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html) to interpolate it's volume of the first track down and the inverted volume value to bump up the second track with a nice cross fade

Have fun!